# Trace/BPT trap in C++ program in AIX Box

Tags: c++, aix

I get the Trace/BPT trap core dump, when I try to run my exe.  Please let me know your suggestions.

```
  time /backup/SStore/CODE/Smain.exe 00257947
SROMain running with trace level. 0

 InitEstimateServer
About to SetUpStockBuildMonitorSet up StockBuildMonitorProcessed 2 records

Trace/BPT trap(coredump)
real    0m14.17s
user    0m9.88s
sys     0m0.08s
```

and after trying to debug it through dbx(core file) below is the output:

```
/usr/bin/dbx32 /backup/SStore/CODE/Smain.exe core
Type 'help' for help.
[using memory image in core]
reading symbolic information ...
Trace/BPT trap in SalcDayList::GetNumberOfDeliveries() at line 92 in file "/backup/SStore/CODE/salclist.C" ($t1)
 92             return m_numberOfDels;
```

Please suggest a remedy....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably got array bounds checking (or something similar) switched on at the compilation stage. That does a trap that produces that message.

Fix your array bound error - I imagine it may have been on the line before.

Comment: I get this error only when I try to get the profiling information for this source code, and changing the make file in such a way to obtain the profiling information. I included -pg flag while compiling the executable.